# define html checkbox in struts 1.3

Tags: struts-1

hi i try to build crud with struts 1.3 
this my page jsp

```
<logic:notEmpty name="Listprojects">
                        <logic:iterate id="remonter" indexId="i" name="Listprojects" type="entitiesMysql.Remonter" >
                            <tr>

                            <td>
                                    <%--<bean:define id="leadId" name="lead" property="id" />--%>
                                    <html:checkbox property="projectsIds" value="<%=Listprojects.getId().toString()%>" styleId="<%=i.toString()%>" />
                                </td>
                                <td><bean:write name="remonter" property="id" /></td>
                                <td><bean:write name="remonter" property="name" /></td>

                            </tr>
                       </logic:iterate>
                    </logic:notEmpty>
```

my problem is in class jsp i cant define checkbox:

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVRny.png)

Comment: Aren't you trying to mix scriptlet and tag values here?

Answer (score 0):

my solution is : 
**add this code in your jsp page:**

```
<div class="center">
<tr> <th><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="CR" id="remontercr" onclick="selectAllCR(this);" tabindex="8"/>&nbsp;<b>Remonter de C.P au C.R</b></th>
                                         <th><input type="checkbox"  name="PROD" value="2" id="remonterprod" onclick="selectAll(this);" tabindex="8"/>&nbsp;<b>Remonter de C.R au PROD</b></th></tr> </div>
```

to recover value of checkbox

```
public class GestionremonterAction extends Action {
    
     @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException, InterruptedException {
/* code......*/


 String decisioncocherCR=request.getParameter("PROD");
}
```